# Shiny server functions with 2 outputs

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to return two tables based on one input.  Basically, I'm reading in a CSV and I want to display the values in the CSV in a table, then in a second table display a count of the number of rows in the CSV.

Right now I have

**ui.R**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv")
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("rawData"),
      tableOutput("rawDataSize")
    )
  )
)
```

and **server.R**

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$rawData <- renderTable({
    inFile <- reactive({input$file1})
    data <- reactive({
      if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
      read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
    })
  })

  output$rawDataSize <- renderTable({
    dim(data)[1]
  })

}
```

Unfortunately, this returns `Warning: Error in as.data.frame.default: cannot coerce class "c("reactiveExpr", "reactive")" to a data.frame`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `inFile <- reactive({input$file1})` outside of `renderTable`. Then, to use this reactive object, you need to treat it like a function. `inFile()$datapath`. Same for your `data` reactive object.

So, your `server()` ends up looking something like:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  inFile <- reactive({input$file1})

  data <- reactive({
    if (is.null(inFile())) return(NULL)
    read.csv(inFile()$datapath, header = input$header)
  })

  output$rawData <- renderTable({
    data()
  })

  output$rawDataSize <- renderTable({
    dim(data())[1]
  })

}
```

Answer (score 2):

1- A reactive is a function, so always add `()` when calling it.

2- Avoid nesting reactives:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  inFile <- reactive(input$file1)

  data <- reactive({
      if (is.null(inFile()))
          return(NULL)
      read.csv(inFile()$datapath, header = input$header)
      })

  output$rawData <- renderTable(data())

  output$rawDataSize <- renderTable(dim(data())[1])
}
```